# Scrollable div/panel in flexbox layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to make panels/divs scrollable, but they have dynamic heights. So far, the only solutions I found are using arbitrary heights in various units, which I would like to avoid. I’m trying to go the Flex route but I’m missing something...

```css
.app {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #f4f3ef;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid red;

  .topbar {
    border: 2px solid lightblue;
    padding: 8px;
  }

  .container {
    display: flex;
    border: 2px dashed lightpink;

    .panel {
      border: 2px solid lightgreen;
      background-color: #f4f3efbb;
      padding: 8px;
      flex: 1;

      .tabs {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
        padding-bottom: 8px;

        & > button:not(:first-child) {
          margin-left: 20px;
        }
      }

      .input-container {
        padding: 8px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
      }

      .scrollable {
        overflow-y: auto;

        p.message {
          color: salmon;
          font-weight: 500;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

.note {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p class="note">The red border represents the viewport</note>
<div class="app">
  <div class="topbar">Lorem ...</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="panel left-side">
      <div class="tabs">
        <button>Tab 1</button>
        <button>Tab 2</button>
      </div>
      <div class="body">
        <div class="input-container">
          <input placeholder="Type something" />
          <button>Send</button>
        </div>
        <divp class="scrollable">
          <p class="message">This panel should be scrollable if it overflows</p>Lorem ...
          Lorem ...
          Lorem ...
        </divp>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel center-side">
      <divp class="scrollable">
        <p class="message">This panel should be scrollable if it overflows</p>Lorem ...
          Lorem ...
      </divp>
    </div>
    <div class="panel right-side">
      <div class="tabs">
        <button>Tab 1</button>
        <button>Tab 2</button>
        <button>Tab 3</button>
        <button>Tab 4</button>
      </div>
      <div class="scrollable">
        <p class="message">This panel should be scrollable if it overflows</p>Lorem...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here’s a CodePen of a simplified version of my app: https://codepen.io/hubchau/pen/qBPqJRd

Answer (score 0):

I set my content flexbox with `min-height: 100%;` and `overflow: auto;`:

https://codepen.io/logany-hi/pen/PoKLzWp?editors=1100

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.body{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
}

/* SIDEBAR --------------------------------*/
.sidebar {
  width: 340px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #021334;
}
.sidebar header {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  background: #283562;
}

.sidebar ul {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-left: 0;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  margin-top: 2px;
}
.sidebar ul li.menuHeader {
  padding: 15px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-top: 1px solid #021334;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #021334;
}
.sidebar ul a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 15px 17px 50px;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #283652;
}
.sidebar ul a:hover,
.sidebar ul a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #283652;
}

/* CONTENT ------------------------------------ */
.main {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.breadcrumbs {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b6bcc6;
}
.breadcrumbs ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.breadcrumbs ul li {
  line-height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}

.box {
  min-height: -webkit-min-content;
  width:100%;
}

.page-content {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<main class="body">
  <nav class="sidebar">
    <header>
      Ortund
    </header>
    <ul>
      <li class="menuHeader">Basics</li>
      <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/Products">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="/Services">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="/About">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="/Contact">Contact Us</a></li>
      
      <li class="menuHeader">Admin</li>
      <li><a href="/KPAs">Manage KPAs</a></li>
  </nav>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="page-header breadcrumbs">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li>.::.</li>
        <li><a href="/KPAs/Create">KPAs</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      <div class="box">

        <div class="page-content">
          <div style="margin-top: 5px;">
            <h3>Add KPAs</h3>
          </div>

          <div style="padding: 20px 0;">
            <div class="card" style="width: 800px; margin-bottom: 50px;">
              <div class="card-body">
                <form id="createForm" method="post">

                  <div class="form-group row pb-2">
                    <label class="col-sm-4" for="KPA_Evaluation_Id">Evaluation</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <select class="form-control" id="KPA_Evaluation_Id" name="KPA.Evaluation.Id">
                        <option value="">No evaluation</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group row pb-2">
                    <label class="col-sm-4" for="item_Name">KPA 1</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="item_Name" name="item.Name" value="" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group row pb-2">
                    <label class="col-sm-4" for="item_Description">Description</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <textarea class="form-control" id="item_Description" name="item.Description">
</textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group row pb-2">
                    <label class="col-sm-4" for="item_Name">KPA 2</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="item_Name" name="item.Name" value="" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group row pb-2">
                    <label class="col-sm-4" for="item_Description">Description</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <textarea class="form-control" id="item_Description" name="item.Description">
</textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group row pb-2">
                    <label class="col-sm-4" for="item_Name">KPA 3</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="item_Name" name="item.Name" value="" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group row pb-2">
                    <label class="col-sm-4" for="item_Description">Description</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <textarea class="form-control" id="item_Description" name="item.Description">
</textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  
                  <div class="form-group row pb-2">
                    <label class="col-sm-4" for="item_Name">KPA 4</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="item_Name" name="item.Name" value="" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group row pb-2">
                    <label class="col-sm-4" for="item_Description">Description</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <textarea class="form-control" id="item_Description" name="item.Description">
</textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  
                  <div class="form-group row pb-2">
                    <label class="col-sm-4" for="item_Name">KPA 5</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="item_Name" name="item.Name" value="" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-sm-4" for="item_Description">Description</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <textarea class="form-control" id="item_Description" name="item.Description">
</textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  
                    <div class="fixed-bottom border-top p-3 bg-white" style="left: 340px;">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ly-button text-white save">Create</button>
                        <a onclick="window.history.go(-1); return false;"
                            class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm ly-button"
                            style="margin-left:10px; cursor:pointer;">Cancel</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
</main>
```